# Reading XML From HTTP Android

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to read an xml file from the internet.

This is the code i'm using:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mypage.com/version.xml");
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httppost);
```

and I'm getting this ex:

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

I'm trying to do this with an async method following the answers.
This is the code I tried:

```
public class Download extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document> {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private Exception exception;
public Document document;

public Download(String url)
{
    this.execute(url);
}

@Override
protected Document doInBackground(String... url) {
    try {
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(url.toString());
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = builder.parse(response.getEntity().getContent());
            return document;
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Download failed, HTTP response code "
                    + statusCode + " - " + statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }            

    } catch (Exception e) {
        exception = e;
        return null;
    }
}

protected void onPostExecute(Document doc)
{
    // TODO: check this.exception 
    // TODO: do something with the feed
    document = doc;
}

}
```

But the document is null.

Comment: Did you read the exception? Use a background thread.

Comment: It is better to avoid network operations on main thread.

Comment: Check this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Answer (score 0):

Try to include the Web Call logic inside the `AsyncTask`.

FYI, you can do background process inside the `doInBackground()` method of AsyncTask.

Comment: Or to get rid of problems with orientation change, go with `AsyncTaskLoader`